# Suitable Shuffling algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, random

Just checking that this shuffling algorithm is suitable. Or maybe there could be improvements?

```
public static void shuffleArray(Object[] arr, Random rnd){
    int lastIndex = arr.length - 1;
    for (int i=0; i<=lastIndex; i++){
        int k = rnd.nextInt(lastIndex+1);
        Object a = arr[i];
        Object b = arr[k];
        arr[i] = b;
        arr[k] = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this question should belong to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Seems ok to me. Is there something special you want to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

Your random number should be chosen in the range i..lastIndex+1 rather than the range 0..lastIndex+1. Google for Fisher-Yates shuffle for an explanation.

You could also save one assignment during the swap by copying directly from one array location to the other without an intermediary: x = arr[i], arr[i] = arr[k], arr[k] = x.

Comment: Thanks, it seems I missed the i..lastIndex+1 when translating my pseudocode! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If by suitable you are saying uniformly distributed, then no, it is not. Considering the fact that for each iteration, with each of the possible configurations, you generate N possible next configurations with equal probability. In the end, you have `N ^ N` equal possibilities, while there's just `N!` permutations, and the former in the normal case cannot be divided by the latter, thus impossible to be uniformly distributed.

In fact, I think Jeff Attwood has a explanation here:

[Coding Horror - The danger of naivete](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html)

Answer (score 1):

> I need this to shuffle an array of char(s)

You can adapt the shuffle code like this for primitives

```
public static void shuffle(char[] chars, Random rnd) {
    int size = chars.length;
    for (int i = size; i > 1; i--) {
        int idx = rnd.nextInt(i);
        char tmp = chars[idx];
        chars[idx] = chars[i-1];
        chars[i-1] = tmp;
    }
}
```

---

You could just do

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(array), random);
```

Or you could look at this code.  It is slightly more efficient to use one temporary variable and reduce the size of the random as you go.  See Collections.shuffle for how to do this.

```
public static void shuffle(List<?> list, Random rnd) {
    int size = list.size();
    if (size < SHUFFLE_THRESHOLD || list instanceof RandomAccess) {
        for (int i=size; i>1; i--)
            swap(list, i-1, rnd.nextInt(i));
    } else {

public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j) {
    final List l = list;
    l.set(i, l.set(j, l.get(i)));
}
```

Note: you are doing `(lastIndex+1)` but lastIndex is `arr.length - 1` so really this is just `arr.length`

Comment: I don't think this method works with primitive arrays. I need this to shuffle an array of `char`(s)

Comment: You can use the same approach.  If you need to work with primitives, you could make this more obvious in your question.

Comment: @Kurent added an example for a `char[]`